# HTML / Mail System / SMTP Not sending approval in html

Tags: emails

I have a current Drupal site that sends out all emails using the HTML template. Users requests, reset password, webform but does not send out approvals in HTML. Anyone have this issue or know a solution?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I believe drupal will only send text emails by default. You will need a module to help you implement HTML emails. I have used Mime Mail in the past to do this.

https://www.drupal.org/project/mimemail

From drupal.org:

> This is a Mime Mail component module (for use by other modules).
>
> - It permits users to receive HTML email and can be used by other
>     modules. The mail functionality accepts an HTML message body,
>     mime-endcodes it and sends it.
> - If the HTML has embedded graphics,
>     these graphics are MIME-encoded and included as a message attachment.
> - Adopts your site's style by automatically including your theme's
>     stylesheet files in a themeable HTML message format
> - If the
>     recipient's preference is available and they prefer plaintext, the
>     HTML will be converted to plain text and sent as-is. Otherwise, the
>     email will be sent in themeable HTML with a plaintext alternative.
> - Allows you to theme messages with a specific mailkey. Converts CSS
>     styles into inline style attributes.
> - Provides simple system actions
>     and Rules actions to send HTML email with embedded images and
>     attachments.

Comment: I do have those installed. But what is weird is everything sends out as html email but not the approval.